# How to return a value from tuple

Tags: python, list, for-loop, while-loop, tuples

Okay, so say I have a tuple like this

```
values = ('1', 'cat', '2', 'bat', '3', 'rat', '4', 'hat', '5', 'sat')
```

What loop function would I have to write to ask for a user input for the integer and have it return the word. ie. user inputs 1 and it returns cat. or user inputs 123 and it returns catbatrat (i dont need the output to be have spaces)

edit: I know it would make more sense to use a dictionary, but in this instance, i would not like to.

my code:

```
    values = ('1', 'cat', '2', 'bat', '3', 'rat', '4', 'hat', '5', 'sat')
    message = raw_input("Enter a number for the corresponding word: ")
    for char in message:
        print values
```

Comment: 1) Please show us your solution attempt. 2) Add a language tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say, this is much better done via dictionary. But since you insist: you can look up the index for the number in the tuple, and then print the element at the next index:

```
for char in message:
    print values[values.index(char)+1],
```

With input `'123'`, will print:

```
cat bat rat
```

Note that this will fail horribly if any of the characters entered aren't present since the `index` method will raise an exception.

I'm wondering if you just want to know how to access individual tuple elements; you can index them just like you would a list. For example, given:

```
values = ('cat', 'rat', 'bat', 'hat')
```

You could just say `values[0]` to get `'cat'`, for example.